# Use awk to print first column, second column and one every 3 columns thereafter and print only rows matching criteria

Tags: awk

I'm trying to get awk to print the first column, second column and one column every 4 after that (Eg. 1,2,6,10, etc). I also want to remove the second row because this is a header with unimportant stuff. Lastly, I want to filter rows based on the value of the first column (supplied as a vector of strings).

Let's take this example, and say I only want rows matching 'table' or 'chair':

```
string  number1 junk1   junk2   junk3   number2 junk4   junk5   junk6   number3
junk7   junk8   junk9   junk10  junk11  junk12  junk13  junk14  junk15  junk16
car     7       x1      x5      x9      3       x13     x17     x21     11
table   8       x2      x6      x10     5       x14     x18     x22     2
chair   9       x3      x7      x11     4       x15     x19     x23     6
comb    0       x4      x8      x12     1       x16     x20     x24     10
```

I would want to have this as output

```
string  number1 number2 number3
table   8   5   2
chair   9   4   6
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a working solution using awk that pipes to grep that is very slow but not one using only awk. I have another topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950514/use-awk-to-print-first-column-second-column-and-one-column-every-four-after-tha but was asked to make a new question to build on

Comment: What form does the list of words to match come in? A file, or a shell array, or what?

Comment: I'm dynamically calling awk code from R to use data.table to load the resulting data. The awk line is therefore generated on the fly. So it could be for example an array in awk that is generated on the fly. The answer below could work if its possible and feasible to have 1000+ || statements joined together.

Comment: If you're generating the code then you could define an array like `a["table"]; a["chair"];` etc. in the `BEGIN` block then use a test `$1 in a`. However, if you're already using R then I'm not sure why you're going down this route at all - wouldn't it make more sense to use R?

Comment: The input files are ~50 GB, even using data.table it's extremely slow to process. Luckily data.table fread allows you to supply commands which are first evaluated prior to loading which speeds things up considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your columns are limited to 10

```
 awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR!=2 && /table/ || /chair/ || NR==1{print $1,$2,$6,$10}'
```

if column count is not known, or too many to enumerate you can do this.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR!=2 && /table/ || /chair/ || NR==1{line=$1 OFS $2; for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=4)line=line OFS $i; print line}'
```

you can also externalize the filter into a variable, such as

```
awk -v filter="chair table" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR==1 || (NR!=2 && (filter ~ $1)) {line=$1 OFS $2; for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=4)line=line OFS $i; print line}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the number columns is unknown, can be several hundred.

Comment: The second one works perfectly! Is it also possible to make the vector of variables that the first column should match to a dynamic variable? So that it does not have to be known or limited to two?

Comment: This works with the command being generated on the fly:

cmd = sprintf('awk -v filter="%s" \'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR==1 || (NR!=2 && (filter ~ $1)) {line=$1 OFS $2; for(i=6;i<=NF;i+=4)line=line OFS $i; print line}\' "%s/%s"', probes_regex, datadir, f)dat = fread(cmd)

Comment: Try that when you want to only select lines that start with the keyword `car` and your input data contains a line that starts with `carpet`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v keys='table|chair' 'NR==1 || (NR>2 && $1~"^("keys")$") {out=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=4) out = out OFS $i; print out}' file
string number1 number2 number3
table 8 5 2
chair 9 4 6
```

The above assumes your keys do not contain RE metacharacters, if they can then edit your question to show that and you'll need a different solution.